# Convert DER .cer format to Base64 .CER

Tags: openssl, certificate

I have exported my certificates in `DER` encodig (with the extension .cer).
Is there a way to convert those certificates in `Base-64` encoding (with the same extension)?
Thanks

Comment: The extension (as all the filename) is irrelevant. It only exists to make human life easier, computers do not care, only the content of the file matters for them. "Base-64 encoding" is called PEM in the "SSL"  world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert from a DER to a base64, you can use **certutil** :

```
certutil -encode filename.cer newfilename.cer
```

And from a base64 to a DER, you can use :

```
certutil -decode filename.cer newfilename.cer
```

Comment: Tanks for the help ;)

Comment: `certutil` is not part of the OpenSSL suite of tools as far as I know.

Answer (score 14):

As you have the `openssl` tag on your question, you should use:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in infile.cer -out outfile.cer
```

In the reverse direction:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in infile.cer -out outfile.cer
```